# Illegal jobs, warrant issues and particular scenario

Tags: firefly

The other day playing Firefly with friends, we were playing a scenario where when completing an illegal job you get issued a warrant.

As far we understand from the basic rules, all your jobs (legal or illegal) get cancelled when you get issued a warrant.

That would imply that you can be working at most one job when doing illegal jobs throughout the game making the game slightly slower, regardless the fact that illegal jobs get you more money.

Is there something we missed or is this the proper and expected behavior of such scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only discard an Active Job if you get issued a warrant while working that job.

[Firefly Rules](http://www.flamesofwar.com/Portals/0/Documents/Events/FireflyRulebook.pdf), pg 14

> If you receive a Warrant while Working a Job, discard **the** Job, returning it to the discard pile of the issuing Contact.

This is the only mention of discarding Active Jobs when you get a Warrant. You only lose the Job you are using your Work action for, you don't lose other Jobs, and gaining a Warrant outside of a Work action doesn't effect your current Jobs at all.

Comment: That being said, don't forget that you also lose _Reputation_ for that contact if you get a warrant while working a job (for that contact). (Maybe that's what the op was confused about; you lose rep—not other active jobs.)